# Is there any way to give another permission level to a specific folder within a document library?

Tags: permissions, folder, library

I've a document library with several folders in it. Now there was a requirement to set up a new folder in it with special permissions. I'm not sure if this is possible with standard SharePoint practices. I've already seen kinda similar questions to this here in the forum, but none of them solved my problem.

I'm using SharePoint 2013 (I dont have SharePoint Designer 2013).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You click the little ... ellipsis menu on the folder and click Share.

From that pop up, click Shared With and from there click Advanced.

On the corresponding screen, click the Stop Inheriting Permissions button to break permissions inheritance from the parent (the library).

Set permissions as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I didn't see the forest due to too many trees :) Great explanation Eric

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can always brake the inheritance of a folder and assign unique permissions. See my other answer to a similar question:

[How to make a file read only in a folder?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184432/how-to-make-a-file-read-only-in-a-folder/184433#184433)